# Trouble installing msa package via biocManager in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

Whenever I try to install the msa package, I get errors about installation paths and old packages:

```
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: /usr/lib/R/library
  packages:
    boot, class, cluster, KernSmooth, lattice, MASS, Matrix, mgcv,
    nnet, spatial, survival
```

```
Old packages: 'ape', 'blob', 'broom', 'cachem', 'callr',
  'credentials', 'dbplyr', 'DelayedArray', 'desc', 'devtools',
  'diffobj', 'dplyr', 'DT', 'ellipsis', 'furrr', 'future',
  'GenomeInfoDb', 'gert', 'ggplot2', 'gh', 'hardhat', 'hms',
  'htmltools', 'ipred', 'knitr', 'later', 'lifecycle', 'lubridate',
  'MatrixGenerics', 'openssl', 'parsnip', 'phangorn', 'phytools',
  'pillar', 'pkgload', 'processx', 'promises', 'RCurl', 'recipes',
  'reprex', 'reticulate', 'rmarkdown', 'rsample', 'rversions',
  'rvest', 'seqinr', 'slider', 'testthat', 'tibble', 'tidyr',
  'tidyselect', 'tinytex', 'tune', 'usethis', 'vctrs', 'waldo',
  'workflows', 'yardstick'
```

When it asks me if I want to update, it I say yes but it still fails.

Any tips on making the paths writable? I only encounter these issues with bioconductor packages.

Comment: Can you change the `.libPaths`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did a complete reset deleting my old path folders. I reinstalled R and Rstudio afterwards. I don't know what changing the .libPaths would do. I would guess that my currently loaded packages would be cut off from my environments.

Comment: I meant, there must be a default path it is pointing to which may have permission issues.  You may create a new folder with read/write permission and install the package

Comment: Any possible issues with changing the permissions of the folders that appear with ``` .libPaths()``` using ``` sudo chmod a+rwx /filepath/ ```?